# How do I undo my bios changes windows. 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, bios

I'm running windows 8.1 on a toshiba satellite r830. I found a toshiba feature I had never used before and when I enabled it, it told me to update some sort of driver I remember it being a bios?

Since performing this update my laptop crashed a few times and it now no longer makes it to the desktop unless I boot in safe mode.

If I don't boot it in safe mode I get a blue screen with a :( and the error message system_thread_exception_not_handled(athwbx.sys)

Can I undo this change? I have tried system restore but that doesn't work.

Comment: If you saved the changes, and already restarted you can't restore them.  You could of course just disable the feature the same way you enabled it

Comment: well, you could reinstall windows. But that aside. If you turn wireless off on your laptop(the correct function key), can you get into windows in normal mode?

Comment: also this link may be your problem http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Windows-8-8-1/Blue-screen-error-athwbx-sys/td-p/612409   it points you to the right drivers.. so maybe you can go to network connections and uninstall the current ones and use the ones pointed to in that thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it's a BIOS related problem
Try to uninstall and rollback your Atheros Adapters Drivers

Comment: @AndréDaniel: you are very quick in your reply. Yes it's related to `athwbx.sys` in some way and it's mentioned by the author of the question, also in me experience in computer repair BIOS upgrade does not make such a thing.

Comment: In some laptops (I've seen that personally on my Thinkpad T60), BIOS updates can be a bit exotic and update more than just the BIOS, and I know that Atheros cards have an user-upgradeable firmware, so maybe the BIOS update also updated the wireless card's firmware and it doesn't play nicely with the currently installed driver.

Comment: How would I go about rolling back my Atheros Adapters Drivers?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways according to my knowledge:

1. Check out this link: http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-023360.htm
2. Reset motherboard jumper [image] http://www.technibble.com/articlecontent/bios-recovery/bios-reset-jumper.gif

Comment: thing is he wants to go back to what his bios was previously.. rather than reset it to what it was originally.. Also, that will just reset the settings, and if he flashed it with another version then, then resetting the motherboard battery or removing the battery and putting some metal over the thing.. isn't going to put the bios back to the old version.. Though i've heard of recovery BIOSs these days.. Also, my guess is possibly his problem hasn't got much or anything to do with the BIOS anyway!

Comment: But, he can get into windows safe mode so i'm sure he could flash the bios with the original.. that and remove and replace the battery

Comment: my laptop came with windows 7 installed originally, is that going to be an issue?
Is there a way to just install the 8.1 BIOS?

Comment: @Elliot The BIOS version has absolutely nothing to do with the version of Windows. If you want to adjust your BIOS version then I suggest you update it to the latest version possible - the latest often fixes any bugs in earlier ones. It's unlikely your BIOS is the issue by the way. I suppose you could put it back to an earlier one if you can find an  earlier one. Have you tried turning off your wireless adaptor on your laptop and going into windows in normal mode?

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)